# how to replace " \" " in string in lua

Tags: lua

I try to replace the group 2 character \" in my JSON string but not sure why it didnt work.

Here is what i have

```
raw_json_text_edited = string.gsub( raw_json_text, [[\"]], [[]])
```

I also use

```
raw_json_text_edited = string.gsub( raw_json_text, '\"', '')
```

Both way doesnt work since it somehow only remove the " part of string rather than both \"

A bit background about the problem if you have any other suggestion.

I have a long JSON string with

```
..."phone":"{\"p1\":\"13068527218\",\"p2\":\"13062225064\",\"p3\":\"14445554444\"}","email":"{\"e1\":\"test@test.com\",\"e2\":\"test2@test.com\",\"e3\":\"sss@ww.com\"}",....
```

If I remove \" part in this JSON string, everything work.

UPDATE:

WORKING CODE ONLY FOR REPLACING:

```
raw_json_text_edited = string.gsub( raw_json_text, [[\\"]], [[]])
```

However, I just discover a problem why my JSON didnt work is that for JSON string,

```
..."phone":"{\"p1\":\"13068527218\",\"p2\":\"13062225064\",\"p3\":\"14445554444\"}","email":"{\"e1\":\"test@test.com\",\"e2\":\"test2@test.com\",\"e3\":\"sss@ww.com\"}"
```

If i only replace \" then it would be a sub string in "{}", eg: "{"p1":"1213131"}". This is wrong JSON format since table cannot be string.

This problem is something else so I will put this as solved

Comment: Worked fine for me, the second one you tried only removes the `"`. how are you pulling the json?

Comment: I updated the answer for replacing part. I ran into another problem but that is something else different from this. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

raw_json_text_edited = string.gsub( raw_json_text, [[\"]], [[]])